# Where can I download the CONIO.H clone library/source code for Visual C++ 2008 and Win32?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, conio

I need to convert a Turbo C++3.0 based DOS program into Win32 and VC++2008.

It has a text-based GUI interface.

Where can I download the CONIO.H clone library/source code for Visual C++ 2008 and Win32?

Comment: You may find it's less work to upgrade to [C++Builder](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder), since it's a descendant of the same compiler (and of course is Win32 and stuff now too.)  There's a link on the right hand side of that page to a free trial version.

Answer (score 0):

The CONIO.H is a Borland specific header file. You won't find a clone. I would remove the #include statement and fix the calls to functions that it defined.

The changes should not be so dramatic. Somewhat like replaceing `getc()` by `getchar()`. They behave different, since the latter requires pressing the Enter key, but you're in a porting phase anyway.